# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe

i'm using a script **ScriptGlobal.py** that will call and execute 2 other scripts **script1.py** and **script2.py** `exec(open("./script2.py").read())` AND `exec(open("./script1.py").read())`

The output of my script1 is the creation of csv file.
`df1.to_csv('file1.csv',index=False)`

The output of my script2 is the creation of another csv file.
`df2.to_csv('file2.csv',index=False)`

In my **ScriptGlobal.py** i want to read the 2 files file1.csv and file2.csv and then i got this error.

**ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 16, saw 3**

Is there solution to do it without doing manuallyu the manipulation in EXCEL ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try save these two .csv files as ANSI? I had problem with .csv when they were saved as UTF-8.