# How can I import xlsx file in to Jupiter notebook using directory?

Tags: python

I am trying to import an XLSX file into a Jupiter notebook using the code below but I am getting the error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2

How can I resolve this problem?

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_xlsx("C:/Users/name/Downloads/weather_data.xlsx")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117142/parsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-error)

Answer (score -1):

import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_xlsx("C:/Users/name/Downloads/weather_data.xlsx",error_bad_lines=False)

## send a snap shot of your data